# How to call tauri instance inside the actix web server to control window state?

Tags: rust, actix-web, tauri

I have tauri apps that also running a background http services. I want to make this app controllable via http on localhost, but it seems like tauri wont allow me to have that. Here is my main.rs code

```rs
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

use actix_web::web;
use actix_web::{get, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use std::sync::{Once, ONCE_INIT};
use tauri::Manager;
use serde::Deserialize;

static INIT: Once = ONCE_INIT;
static mut APP: Option<tauri::App> = None;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct AppSession {
    action: String,
}

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[get("/actions")]
async fn handle_actions(query: web::Query<AppSession>) -> impl Responder {
    let action = &query.action;
    unsafe {
        if let Some(app) = APP.as_ref() {
            match action.as_str() {
                "session_end" => {
                    app.get_window("main").unwrap().show().unwrap();
                    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Session ending, app shown")
                }
                "session_start" => {
                    app.get_window("main").unwrap().hide().unwrap();
                    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Session starting, app hidden")
                }
                _ => HttpResponse::Ok().body("Unknown action"),
            }
        } else {
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body("App instance not available")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let app = tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_websocket::init())
        .setup(|app| {
            tauri::async_runtime::spawn(
                HttpServer::new(move || {
                    let app = app.clone();
                    App::new()
                        .service(hello)
                        .service(handle_actions)
                        .app_data(app)
                })
                .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
                .expect("Failed to bind address")
                .run(),
            );

            Ok(())
        })
        .build(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");

    INIT.call_once(|| {
        // Initialize your tauri::App instance here
        unsafe {
            APP = Some(app);
        }
    });

    app.run(|_, _| {})
}
```

I tried to use Arc value so I can use the tauri app between thread but it seems not doable, since the code always errored that tauri:App doesn't implement the trait `Send`

```
static INIT: std::sync::Once = std::sync::Once::new();
static mut APP: Option<Arc<Mutex<Option<tauri::App>>>> = None;
```

Right now using the above full code, It still errored in line

```
let app = app.clone()
```

Saying that

```
no method named `clone` found for mutable reference `&mut tauri::App` in the current scope
method not found in `&mut App`
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `OneLock` with Window to initialize global variables. This will store the window reference and can be used to controls Tauri window instances. Here is the complete code :

```rs
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

use std::sync::OnceLock;

use actix_web::web;
use actix_web::{App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use serde::Deserialize;
use tauri::{Manager, Window};

static WINDOW: OnceLock<Window> = OnceLock::new();

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct AppSession {
    event_type: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, serde::Serialize)]
struct Payload {
  message: String,
}

fn main() {
    let app = tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_websocket::init())
        .setup(|app| {
            let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

            _ = WINDOW.set(window);

            async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
                HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
            }

            async fn handle_actions(query: web::Query<AppSession>) -> impl Responder {
                let action = &query.event_type;
                match action.as_str() {
                    "session_end" => {
                        WINDOW.get()
                            .expect("Window is available")
                            .emit("session_end", Payload { message: "Sesion End".into() })
                            .unwrap();
                        HttpResponse::Ok().body("Session ending, app shown")
                    }
                    _ => HttpResponse::Ok().body("Unknown action"),
                }
            }

            tauri::async_runtime::spawn(
                HttpServer::new(move || {
                    App::new()
                        .route("/", web::get().to(hello))
                        .route("/actions", web::get().to(handle_actions))
                })
                .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8081))
                .expect("Failed to bind address")
                .run(),
            );

            Ok(())
        })
        .build(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");

    app.run(|_, _| {})
}
```

Comment: Nice to see you made it work. I couldn't get it correctly, `OnceLock` seems interesting

Answer (score 2):

You have no reason to store a reference to the `app`

```rs
static mut APP: Option<tauri::App> = None;
```

because tauri always gives a handle to you:

```rs
fn function<R: tauri::Runtime>(manager: &impl Manager<R>) {
    let app_handle = manager.app_handle().unwrap();
    // Do thing with app_handle as app
}
```

You just call this function as you would normally:

`function()`, because tauri will fill in the rest.

This also gets rid of your `INIT.call_once`, and it should get rid of `INIT` fully as well.

This should solve your problem with your initial solution, so please let me know if it works. I'll build a full example using your code.

You can also solve your current problem by using a handle again:

```rs
        .setup(|app| {
            let app_handle = app.app_handle();
            // use app_handle instead of the clone
```

Comment: But the function is outside the service.setup. How could I use the app handle?

Comment: I tried, using it in `.service(handle_actions)`. But `async fn handle_actions<R: tauri::Runtime>(manager: &impl Manager<R>,` Errored because the function doesn't implement FromRequest. First time using rust here, lol so sorry if I'm not navigating to the right place that you're reffering to

Comment: yeah, no problem, I'll produce some working code soon to unblock you